# Method for converting diverse JSON files into RDBMS schema?

Tags: python, json, rdbms

I have a large number of JSON documents.  I would like to store them in an RDBMS for querying.  Once there they will never change; it's a data warehousing issue.  I have lots of RDBMS data that I want to match the JSON data with, so it would be inefficient to store the JSON in a more traditional manner (e.g. CouchDB).

From hunting the web, I gather that the best approach might be to create [JSON schema](http://json-schema.org/) files using a tool such as [JSON Schema Generator](https://github.com/perenecabuto/json_schema_generator) and then use that to build a structured RDBMS series of tables.  My data is sufficiently limited in scope (minimal JSON nesting) that I could do this by hand if needed, but a tool that automatically converted from JSON schema to DB DDL statements would be great if it is out there.

My question has two parts but is aimed at the first issue - is there a tool or method by which I can create a master schema that describes all of my data. Many instances are missing various fields (and I have tens of gigabytes of JSON data)?  The second part is with the serialization process.  Does there exist a library (ideally Python) that would take a schema file and a JSON object and output the DML to insert that into a RDBMS?

Answer (score 1):

We just published this package in https://github.com/deepstartup/jsonutils. May be you will find it useful. If you need us to update something, open up a JIRA.
Try:

```
    pip install DDLJ
    from DDLj import genddl
    genddl(*param1,param2,*param3,*param4)

Where
param1= JSON Schema File
param2=Database (Default Oracle)
Param3= Glossary file
Param4= DDL output script
```

Answer (score 0):

Some draft Python for converting JSON to DDL. You'll have to adapt it for JSON schema.

```py
import json
import sys

fp = open(sys.argv[1])
jsobj = json.load(fp)

print "Create table("

for elt in jsobj["fields"]:
    print elt["name"], elt["type"], ","

print ");"
```